# Accidentally accessing random memory, c++

Tags: c++

I need to write a script that counts how many times the numbers 1-9 come up in an array. But when I run the script it prints very large numbers. for example:

0:1;  1:65538; 2:32737; 3:-1697300255; 4:1; 5:4197244; 6:3; 7:6299100; 8:32772; 9:6

Not sure where the error is.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void count_numbers(int array[4][4])
 {
    int num_0, num_1, num_2, num_3 ,num_4, num_5, num_6 , num_7 ,num_8 , num_9 = 0;
    int i, j = 0;

     for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
        switch(array[i][j]){
            case 0:
                num_0++;
            case 1:
                num_1++;
            case 2:
                num_2++;
            case 3:
                num_3++;
            case 4:
                num_4++;
            case 5:
                num_5++;
            case 6:
                num_6++;
            case 7:
                num_7++;
            case 8:
                num_8++;
            case 9:
                num_9++;
        }
    }
}

cout << "0:" << num_0 << ";1:" << num_1 << ";2:" << num_2 << ";3:" << num_3 << ";4:" << num_4 <<";5:" << num_5 << ";6:" << num_6 << ";7:" << num_7 << ";8:" << num_8 << ";9:" << num_9 <<endl;


 }

 #ifndef WEBSUBMIT
 int main()
 {
    int array[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}};
    count_numbers(array);
}
 #endif //WEBSUBMIT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int num_0, num_1, num_2, num_3 ,num_4, num_5, num_6 , num_7 ,num_8 , num_9 = 0;
```

only initializes `num_9` to 0. The other variables are *uninitialized*.

---

It would have been a lot less work to use an array instead of 10 `num_x` variables:

```
void count_numbers(int array[4][4]) {
    int num[10] = {0};
    int i, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] >= 0 && array[i][j] < 10) {
                ++num[array[i][j]];
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        cout << i << ":" << num[i] << ';';
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A statement of the form:

```
int a, b, c = 0;
```

Only initializes `int c`. You want:

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
```

---

Instead of making 10 different variables, you can use an array.

```
int count[10] = {0};
```

This notation initializes the entire array to `0` (Note that if you wrote `{k}` instead of `{0}`, it would initialize only the first element to `k` and the rest of the array to `0`).

`count[i]` would be the number of instances of the digit `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized all you local variables except last variable i.e. num_0,1,2...

int a, b = 0 In this case "a" will remain uninitialized and only "b" will be initialized. Either define them in different lines like

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
```

or

```
int a = 0 , b = 0,
```

or

`static int a, b;   //default initialized to 0, no need to worry about` initialization.